# Htaccess Forward URL from one to another

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, redirect

I need to forward/redirect a domain from

```
  http://local.abcxyz.com/be/country/CN/BE
```

to

```
http://local.abcxyz.com/be/country/visum-china/BE
```

How can I do it using .htaccess ?

my current htaccess file looks like this

```
  RewriteEngine On

    # If the file or directory exists, show it
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
    # Blank queries get sent to the index
    #RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
    # All other queries get sent to the index as index.php/whatever
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /be/index.php/$1 [L]
```

this htaccess exist in be folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/be/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /be/

RewriteRule ^country/CN/BE/?$ country/visum-china/BE [L,NC]

# If the file or directory exists, show it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Assuming there is no .htaccess in `/country/` or any directory below.

Comment: That comment will not help anyone. Q0. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess? Q4. Did you make sure that `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` are enabled?

Comment: I have added all the required info in my question. Existing htaccess, its location as well.

Comment: I dont want to rewrite the url, read the question again I need to Forward that old url to new url. the new url is working fine. what I need is when I enter old url, it automaticaly redirects/forward to new url. Hope it helps everyone.

Comment: @anubhava I think you have not seen the new "this htaccess exist in be folder"

Comment: Q0. What URL are you entering in your browser? 
A0. http://local.abcxyx.com/be/country/CN/BE

Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? 
A1. there are two directories in root, be and nl, there are htaccess in be and nl directories.

Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? 
A2. Same htaccess exists in nl directory.

Q3. What is location of above .htaccess? 
A3. root/be/.htaccess

Q4. Did you make sure that mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled?
A4. I am using CodeIgniter. Htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled.

Comment: @anubhava pls check my answers to your questions.

Comment: this error now i gets "The requested URL /be/country/visum-china/BE was not found on this server."

Comment: So it is clear that rule is correct. Why without `R` it doesn't work might be due to your framework like CodeIgnitor